# Swift 2: Can't call createDirectoryAtUrl with definition

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, swift2

I am currently developing an application on xCode7 beta 2 using Swift 2 (it is a requirement at the moment).

Here is what I am trying to call:

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
let tempDirectoryURL = NSURL(string: NSTemporaryDirectory())!
let directoryURL = tempDirectoryURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("com.test.manager/multipart.form.data")
var error: NSError?

if fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, createIntermediates: true, attributes: nil) {
 ...
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> Cannot invoke 'createDirectoryAtURL' with an argument list of type
>   '(NSURL, createIntermediates: Bool, attributes: nil)'

Which is confusing because the definition for createDirectoryAtURL I am getting when I right click and "view definition" is:

```
 func createDirectoryAtURL(
    url: NSURL, 
    withIntermediateDirectories createIntermediates: Bool, 
    attributes: [String : AnyObject]?
 ) throws
```

The only only paramater that doesn't match verbatim is the last parameter "attributes", which the documentation (and all example usage) explicitly states can accept the value nil.

[Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:):

> If you specify nil for this parameter, the directory is created
>   according to the umask(2) Mac OS X Developer Tools Manual Page of the
>   process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. You've switched an parameter label for its internal name. The second parameter's label — part of the function name, required for calling it — is `withIntermediateDirectories`. The implementor of that function refers to that parameter's value as `createIntermediates`. So your call should look like this:

   ```
   fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
   ```
2. Note the signature you quoted:

   ```
   func createDirectoryAtURL( ... ) throws
   ```

   You're using this call as the condition of an `if` statement — that means you need a function that returns `Bool`. The compiler is trying to satisfy the requirement of the `if` statement by looking for a function called `createDirectoryAtURL` whose type signature is `(NSURL, Bool, [String : AnyObject]?) -> Bool`, and complaining because it only sees one whose signature is `(NSURL, Bool, [String : AnyObject]?) throws -> Void`.

The error handling system in Swift 2 takes ObjC methods that return `BOOL` and have an `NSError` out parameter and turns them into `throw`ing methods with no return type (that is, they return `Void`). So, if you're looking at Swift 1.x code that uses such methods, or porting ObjC code, you need to change patterns like the following:

```
var error: NSError? 
if fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil, error: &error) {
    // all good
} else {
    // handle error
}
```

And use patterns like this instead:

```
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectoryAtURL(directoryURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    // if here, all is good
} catch {
    // handle error
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes a lot of sense. Getting started with Swift2, there are a lot of odd conversions (not necessarily hard, just confusing). Do you think it would make sense if they errored out in a slightly difference format, for example: 'functionName(params)->type expected'.

Comment: The compiler diagnostics could definitely be improved. [File bugs](http://bugreport.apple.com)!

Comment: Filed. Thanks for the recommendation.